# Data sources vs Repository in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, datasource, repository-pattern

I´ve read a quite voted article about implementing [**Data Sources**](https://medium.com/@dcordero/data-sources-in-swift-or-how-to-avoid-that-this-new-trendy-persistency-framework-determines-the-5472fcb75eda) in Swift. In summary it is said that a data source conforms a protocol in order to

> (...) allow the data to be accesed regardless of the specific details of the framework

behind. Then, at the end of the article the **Repository Pattern** as a way to handle different data sources (no further details about the implementation or code snippets provided, though).

On the other hand, I've also read this other article about [**Repository**](https://medium.com/@frederikjacques/repository-design-pattern-in-swift-952061485aa) pattern, and looks pretty much the same as data sources, but just using the names `NRepository`instead of `NDataSource`?

So, are data sources and repositories the same thing? Or is the `Repository` a pattern that makes use of `Data Sources`? In such case... how? Is a `Repository` actually a `Factory` of data sources?